# ElementTree errors, html files will not parse using Python/Sublime

Tags: python, html, parsing, sublimetext2

I am trying to parse a few thousand html files and dump the variables into a csv file (excel spreadsheet). I've come up against several roadblocks, but the first one is this: I can not get it to properly parse the file. Below is a brief explanation, the python code and the traceback info.

Using Python & Sublime to parse html files, I am getting several errors. What IS working: it runs fine up until `if '.html' in file:`. It does not execute that loop. It will iterate through `print allFiles` just fine. It also creates the csv file and creates the headers (though not in separate columns, but I can ask about that later).

It seems that the problem is in the  if `tree = ET.parse(HTML_PATH+"/"+file)` piece. I've written this several different ways (without "/" and/or "file", for example)--so far I have yet to resolve this problem.

If I can provide more information or if anyone can direct me to other documenation, it would be greatly appreciated. So far I have yet to find anything that addresses this issue.

Many thanks for your thoughts.

//C

```
# Parses out data from crawled html files under "html files"
# and places the output in output.csv.

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv, codecs, os
from cStringIO import StringIO
# Note: you need to download and install this..
import unicodecsv

 # TODO: make into command line params (instead of constant)
CSV_FILE='output.csv'
HTML_PATH='/Users/C/data/Folder_NS'
f = open(CSV_FILE, 'wb')
w = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8', delimiter=';')
w.writerow(['file', 'category', 'about', 'title', 'subtitle', 'date', 'bodyarticle'])

# redundant declarations:
category=''
about=''
title=''
subtitle=''
date=''
bodyarticle=''
print "headers created"

allFiles = os.listdir(HTML_PATH)
#with open(CSV_FILE, 'wb') as csvfile:
print "all defined"

for file in allFiles:
    #print allFiles
    if '.html' in file:
        print "in html loop"
        tree = ET.parse(HTML_PATH+"/"+file)
        print '===================='
        print 'Parsing file: '+file
        print '===================='
        for node in tree.iter():
            print "tbody"
            # The tbody attribute spells it all (or does it):
            name = node.attrib.get('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font')

            # Check common header stuff
            if name=='/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font':
                #print '    ------------------'
                #print '  Category:'
                category=node.text
                print "category"

f.close()
```

Traceback:

File "/Users/C/data/Folder_NS/data_parse.py", line 34, in 
    tree = ET.parse(HTML_PATH+"/"+file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 63, column 2

Comment: Have you try "\" or "\\"?

Comment: @ybdesire Yes, I did. It does not work. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to parse HTML with an XML parser, and valid HTML is not always valid XML. You would be better off using the HTML parsing library in the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) package.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# ...
tree = ET.parse(HTML_PATH + '/' + file)
```

would be changed to

```
import lxml.html
# ...
tree = lxml.html.parse(HTML_PATH + '/' + file)
```

Comment: It worked! Now it runs through the loop and hits every html file in the folder, but will it does not parse the html file. I guess I will have to work on that for a while and maybe post another question if I have to. Thank you so much.

Comment: Mayny thanks, i was looking for the same thing then i replaced xml.etree by lxml.html and no more errors :)